# How can I find the area of the triangle on the html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

So I have a rectangle drawn.

When the user clicks anywhere on the canvas I want the area of the top two corner points of the square and the coordinates of the mouse click to be determined in the form of a triangle.

I've googled the formula for the area of a triangle and checked it many times and am sure its right. It's just not working.

I am using: |(Ax(By - Cy) + Bx(Cy - Ay) + Cx(Ay - By))/2|

I'll know  I'll have it right when the area of the triangle is smaller numerically than that of the square, when the user clicks inside the square. The only problem is that it actually comes out much greater, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Trying to figure it out, I played around with mouse coordinates and subtracted from them. This produced results similar to what I want, but I know it's not the precise area of the triangle that I'm trying to determine

If anyone has any insight into this, that would be very much appreciated. 
[image]

```js
window.onload =()=>{
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
   
 const getMousePos =(evt) =>{
        let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left ,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top 
        };
      }  
   class Button {
  constructor(xPos, yPos, width, height) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
}
Button.prototype.draw = function (){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.width, this.height);
};   
Button.prototype.area = function (){
    return (this.width * this.height);
};
Button.prototype.sqToTri = function(mousePos) {
    let farX = this.xPos + this.width;
    let farY = this.yPos + this.height;
    
    let upTri = Math.abs(((this.xPos * (mousePos.y - this.yPos)) + (mousePos.x * (this.yPos - this.yPos)) + (farX * (this.yPos - mousePos.y)))/2);
    
    let buttonArea = this.width * this.height;
    
    alert(upTri);
    alert(buttonArea);
}; 
let redButton = new Button(50, 25, 50, 25);
redButton.draw();

       
       
    canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        let mousePos = getMousePos( evt);
      
   redButton.sqToTri(mousePos);
      }, false);
      

}
```

```css
body{
    height:100%;
}
#canvas {
   width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id='containner'>
        <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The area of the triangle made by the horizontal line A,B and any random point C is

```
upTri = this.width * Math.abs(mousePos.y - this.yPos) * 0.5;
```

Note that the x position of the mouse does not affect the area of the triangle

Answer (score 0):

According to the math formula you have found, shouldn't the code formula be:

let upTri = Math.abs(((this.xPos * (mousePos.y - **farY**)) + (mousePos.x * (**farY** - this.yPos)) + (farX * (this.yPos - mousePos.y)))/2);

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am using the top two corners of the square so that wouldn't affect the y coordinate. I drew an illustration to make this clear in the post. I even double checked the formula again upon reading your post. Thank you for your suggestion. I'm hoping the illustration will make the question clearer.